# How can I send AT commands to raspberry pi 2 serial uart ble module from python script

Tags: gpio, pi-2, serial, bluetooth

Ive connected an hm10 ble to my raspberry pi 2 GPIO pins (3.3V, GND, Rx and Tx).

I've changed the cmdline.txt to 9600 and the inittab is empty.  I downloaded raspbian about 1 week ago.

Im running this python script on the raspberry pi 2 to try and send commands to the ble module.  I cant get the module to respond:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import serial

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/serial0',9600,parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,timeout=None)

while True:
        ser.write("AT")
        data = ser.read()
        ser.write(data)
```

I just get an empty prompt and no response in terminal.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Got it working.  Ended up posting the answer on my original raspberry.org forum post here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=158856&p=1032763#p1032763

Basically I had to change AT+IMME = 1

Answer (score 0):

try this out

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB2',9600,parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,tim> 
while True:
    ser.write(bytes("AT\r\n", 'utf-8'))
    data = ser.read()
    print(data)
```